# Use method name for SublimeText 2 autocomplete as well as tab trigger

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets

The default SublimeText 2 snippets, located in the `Packages` directory and then under, say, `Ruby` are useful but only if you happen to know the tab trigger. For example the file `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Ruby/alias_method-..-(am).sublime-snippet` contains:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[alias_method :${1:new_name}, :${0:old_name}]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>am</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.ruby</scope>
    <description>alias_method ..</description>
</snippet>
```

So we can access this trigger by hitting `am` then `tab`.

My question is, if this snippet chucks in `alias_method :${1:new_name}, :${0:old_name}` isn't there a way that I can use this snippet without knowing its `am` trigger, just by starting to type `alias_m...` for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm, no, not that I can find. I just opened up a blank Ruby file, hit `a`, and autocomplete popped up with all sorts of options, including the snippet you mentioned. However, if I then typed an `l` (starting to spell out `alias...`), the option for the `am` snippet disappeared. So, it looks like autocomplete is not searching the `<description>` field, only the `<tabTrigger>` field. There aren't any options in `Preferences -> Settings - Default` that would seem to address this situation.

So, unfortunately it would seem the solution is one of two things - either edit all your commonly-used snippets to have tabTriggers that make more sense to you, or put together a snippet cheat sheet. It looks like at least one other person was thinking the same thing, as I found [this collection](https://github.com/manusajith/sublime-cheatsheets) without too much searching.

Good luck!

Comment: Didn't think so, just wanted to make sure I hadn't missed something!